# NodeJS: Axios sets default host in request header as "127.0.0.1" instead of "localhost"

Tags: node.js, axios, localhost

From my NodeJS server application I am sending request to another server. This is how Axios request looks like:

```
  axios({
    method: "GET",
    url: "https://base.url.to.another.server/myapi",
    })
    .catch(function (error) 
    {
      if (error) 
        return reject(error);
    })
    .then(function (resp) 
    {
      resolve(resp);
      return resp;
    });
```

This works fine except that recipient server gets `Host` value as '127.0.0.1' instead of 'localhost' causing it to raise exception (because of security related policies applied there)/ When I send same request through browser, it gets correct value `Host: 'localhost'` in request header.

Question:

How can I make Axios to set 'host' value in request header as 'localhost' instead of '127.0.0.1'?

What did I try?

Tried setting this as header, but without any success.

```
    headers:
    {
      'host': 'localhost:8080'
    }
```